# Flutter Zoom IOS

Tags: flutter

Error (Xcode): The file “/Users/almubdie/StudioProjects/flutter-zoom-video-sdk-5.14.0-1.7.0/example/ios/Runner/Runner.entitlements” could not be opened. Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target “Runner” is correct and that the file exists on disk.
StudioProjects/flutter-zoom-video-sdk-5.14.0-1.7.0/example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj

Error (Xcode): The file “/Users/almubdie/StudioProjects/flutter-zoom-video-sdk-5.14.0-1.7.0/example/ios/ScreenShare/ScreenShare.entitlements” could not be opened. Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target “ScreenShare” is correct and that the file exists on disk.
StudioProjects/flutter-zoom-video-sdk-5.14.0-1.7.0/example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj

I simply copied zoom flutter sdk from there site upon running I am getting this error